# react.js useState hook is assigned a value but not used, but that is ok

Tags: reactjs, onclick, render

I have this setup so that the render is forces when they click by simply updating the state of a hook. Is there a nicer or cleaner way to do this.. here is some code...

```
const [click, setClick] = useState();

function handle1Click() {
    props.UserInfoObject.setWhichPlot(1)
    setClick(1000 * 60 * 5)
}

return (
    <div>
        <button onClick={handle1Click}>5 Minutes</button>
    </div>
```

I came accross this which is another option but I am trying to be as optimal as possible so I am unsure which to use, or if there is another method?

```
  handleClick = () => {
    // force a re-render
    this.forceUpdate();
  };
```

I only mention this because of the warning that pops up stating this "'click' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars

***EDIT
adding the UserInfoObject class for reference

```
class UserInformation {
    constructor(airValue, waterValue){
        this.airValue = airValue;
        this.waterValue = waterValue;
        this.getCalibrationsFlag = false;
        this.numberDevices = 0;
        this.deviceName = 'defaultName';
        this.currentlyChangingName = false;
        this.whichPlot = 1;
    }
    setAirValue(number) {
        this.airValue = number;
    }
    setWaterValue(number) {
        this.waterValue = number;
    }
    setNumberDevices(int){
        this.numberDevices = int;
    }
    setDeviceName(name){
        this.deviceName = name;
    }
    setCurrentlyChangingName(boolean){
        this.currentlyChangingName = boolean;
    }
    setWhichPlot(number){
        this.whichPlot = number;
    }
}

let UserInfoObject = new UserInformation(10000, -10);
```

Comment: What is `props.UserInfoObject.setWhichPlot(1)`, what does that do?

Comment: I have an object called UserInfoObject that I am sending down as a prop. I then have functions to change its values as I move along through my flow. It is basically how I am managing state. I come from OOP background so it may not be best for react

Comment: Also, when the re-render is triggered via new "click" state, the object is updated and passes down the updates

Comment: Can you show the code of `UserInfoObject` including `setWhichPlot`?

Comment: Ok I added it above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With React, you should generally use pure, functional programming when possible. Mutating objects makes it much, much harder to do things properly.

Create *state* of the `UserInformation` instead. When it needs to be changed, instead of mutating the existing object, create a new object. The fact that this object is new will tell React that the component needs to re-render.

```
const [userInformation, setUserInformation] = useState({
  airValue, // this should be in the outer scope
  waterValue, // this should be in the outer scope
  getCalibrationsFlag: false,
  numberDevices: 0,
  // ...
});
```

Do that in the parent component, then pass both `userInformation` and `setUserInformation` down as props. In the child, `handle1Click` can then be changed to:

```
const handle1Click = () => setUserInformation({
  ...userInformation,
  whichPlot: 1,
});
```

Neither state nor props should ever be mutated in React.

Comment: ah. I was close. lol very nice. Thank you for this! I will restructure the app.

Comment: If I am passing state down as a prop, how would I setState? I tried props.setUserInformation with no luck

Comment: Make sure to pass `setUserInformation` down as a prop. Eg your code might be something like `<Child userInformation={userInformation} setUserInformation={setUserInformation}>` and then the state setter will be callable in the child.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!