# React useContext hook, need only the function not the variable

Tags: reactjs, use-context

How do I stop React dev warnings from filling my console with yellow kaka?

I need only the function, not the variable.

(Telling me: `'user' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars`)

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import { UserContext } from "../../contexts/userContext";

const Dev = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useContext(UserContext);

  return (
    <form onSubmit={() => "blah blah blah"}>
      <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setUser(e.target.value)} />
    </form>
  );
};

export default Dev;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that in fact all you need to do is this:

```
const [, setUser] = useContext(UserContext);
```

Looks wrong, but works.

Answer (score 0):

Errors and warnings in development builds are displayed in LogBox inside your app.

Here is an example you can use :

```
LogBox.ignoreLogs([" 'user' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars"]);
```

These notifications can be hidden using LogBox.ignoreAllLogs().

You can check more in [Debugging](https://reactnative.dev/docs/debugging#logbox)

Comment: Still wants to warn me though, it should be possible to use only the function without having the variable hanging around.

Comment: Try checking this post here if possible , it explains how you have to set up for your code without the need to ignoreLogs [react.js useState hook is assigned a value but not used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65693830/react-js-usestate-hook-is-assigned-a-value-but-not-used-but-that-is-ok)